# Cannot add cell to table content: total cell count of 837114417 exceeded

Tags: psql

I tried to make an inner join query between two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Tweets INNER JOIN Users ON (Tweets.user_0 = Users.id);
```

And this error message appeared:

**Postgresql: Cannot add cell to table content: total cell count of 837114417 exceeded.**

These tables (Tweets and Users) are very big, But is there a way to execute this query anyway?
When I ran this query on the same table with fewer lines the query worked properly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of whether you need the entire result set?  Perhaps you can add a `WHERE` clause, or subquery, to avoid this error.

Comment: I have to use exactly this query to measure the running time.

Comment: To just  measure the running time, reduce the number of columns, or  add COUNT(*) :`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...JOIN ...ON ...;`

Comment: What client software are you using? It is likely responsible for the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error stems from your `psql` **frontend**, while trying to format and display a huge number of rows and columns. The code is in [`src/fe_utils/print.c` around line 3000](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/fe_utils/print.c;h=cb9a9a06131931dbb23809ec2ea9d9f6a908fae1;hb=9c0a0de4c91b2dc911220d769cf2c5f754cfcb90#l2997).

The query was actually executed, but when the DBMS sends the result back to `psql` , it is too much data to swallow. (psql needs to buffer the complete result, just to estimate the needed column widths.)

Comment: `void
printTableAddCell(printTableContent *const content, char *cell,
                                  const bool translate, const bool mustfree)
{`

Comment: I started with 9.5 But 10.x and11.x had it too.